# query key condition not supported between c# AWS Dynomodb

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am getting result from dynomoDb using QueryRequest, If i am sending emp_id alone it's returning the result. Suppose if i am passing one more query parameter it's returning

> **query key condition not supported**

Please check mentioned below code, let me know if there is any mistake on this.

```
 var _request = new QueryRequest
            {
                TableName = "Attendence",
                KeyConditionExpression = "Roster_EmpID = :Roster_EmpID and Roster_CreatedDateTime between :v_start and :v_end",
                ExpressionAttributeValues = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue> {
                    {":Roster_EmpID", new AttributeValue {  S = result.empId    }}
                    ,{":v_start", new AttributeValue {   S = result.fromDate.ToString(AWSSDKUtils.ISO8601DateFormat)  }}
                    ,{":v_end", new AttributeValue { S = result.toDate.ToString(AWSSDKUtils.ISO8601DateFormat)    }}
                },
                IndexName = "Roster_EmpID-index"
            };
```

Even I am passing aws date format(AWSSDKUtils.ISO8601DateFormat), there is hard to find the solution. Please help me to find the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use Filter

```
            var _request = new QueryRequest
            {
                TableName = "Attendence",
                KeyConditionExpression = "Roster_EmpID = :Roster_EmpID",// and Roster_Date between :v_start and :v_end",
                FilterExpression = "Roster_Date between :v_start and :v_end",
                ExpressionAttributeValues = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue> {
                    {":Roster_EmpID", new AttributeValue {  S = result.empId    }}
                    ,{":v_start", new AttributeValue {   S = result.fromDate.ToString(AWSSDKUtils.ISO8601DateFormat)  }}
                   ,{":v_end", new AttributeValue { S = result.toDate.ToString(AWSSDKUtils.ISO8601DateFormat)    }}
                },
                IndexName = "Roster_EmpID-index"
            };
```

Else need to create index using add sort key and need to use that index name.

[Sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dewzu.png)